# How to pass variable from html to android java class?

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

I have created the plugin for background service from the help of this link

[How to create plugin in phonegap to run the application in background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9412501/how-to-create-plugin-in-phonegap-to-run-the-application-in-background)

But now my problem is pass the variable from index.html to backgroundservice.java from there i need to pass that variable to Myservice.class.

please guide me.thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

See the [AccountList](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/AccountList) plugin for a small example of a plugin that takes a JavaScript parameter (type).