# Run Android phonegap application in background

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile, cordova-2.0.0

I am developing an android application in Phonegap, cordova.. 
I had a button in the application, while clicking in that I need to run the application in the background and

need to call a web service at the interval of 15 mins.

Is it possible in phone gap, cordova proj...

I am new to this..Please help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will have to create a custom plugin in order to run processes in the background. You can find a plugin implementation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9412501/how-to-create-plugin-in-phonegap-to-run-the-application-in-background).

Answer (score 1):

In the onCreate method of your Java class that extends from DroidGap make sure you have set "keepRunning" properly.

```
        super.setBooleanProperty("keepRunning", true);
```

Answer (score 1):

As of phonegap 3+, there's a plugin to add this functionality to your application, here's the link to the plugin project and instructions, should work for cordova, phonegap and phonegap build:

https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode/blob/ac5fef831dbf9e567277dc900389923bd9bc7714/README.md