# MobileFirst app running while device is locked?

Tags: android, ios, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

On the initial load of our application, we make hundreds of worklight invokeProcedure calls, that take up to 20 minutes to an hour to fully complete.  (Each one takes less than 10 seconds, so works fine.)  However if the device lock screen comes up it pauses the application and if I don't respond quickly enough to the device lock screen, the worklight invokeProcedure gets interrupted and stops our initial load process.

Is there a way to configure the application on Windows, iOS, and Android to continue when the lock screen is showing?

Comment: Hundreds of invoke procedure calls? Couldn't you try chaining the adapter calls ( in the server) as much as you can

Comment: No, we intentionally chunk them into smaller pieces, so each one is shorter than the socket timeouts between the worklight and backend servers.  The problem is that the app pauses, and it causes the invokeProcedure to fail.

Comment: What version of MobileFirst?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at a combination of preventing the screen lock from occurring and the background handling Idan Adar suggests, to provide a more graceful and controllable UX.

For iOS, setting the idelTimerDisabled property at the right places in your processing could prevent the screen lock, and then if other external device operations occur, you could gracefully complete and save process state of the rest of your procedure calls, resuming them when the app becomes active again.

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES;
```

A similar approach should be supported in other platforms.

Comment: We were able to find a way to disable the lock screen in Windows and will continue this approach for Android and iOS. The background fetch setting surprisingly didn't work for us on iOS the app continued to pause when the screen was locked.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a built-in functionality AFAIK.

For iOS, you need to enable "background fetch" mode:
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/ios_background_fetch?lang=en

For Android you may need to do this with a Cordova plug-in: [IBM Worklight - How to use Worklight in a background process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17493719/ibm-worklight-how-to-use-worklight-in-a-background-process)

As for Windows... no idea...